# Does Admob supports VAST ads?

Tags: android, admob, vast

I have implemented banner and interstitial ads using admob sdk and now want to show video ads, I googled for sample source code for admob vast but could not find any.
I have tried using interstitial sample with VAST ad unit on dfp campaign management system but its failing.
Have any one tried admob with VAST?

Comment: Any details on why it's failing, errortracker or SDK debug message? What tag have you been testing with and how did you configure the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using ima sdk from google for VAST.
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/

Comment: It looks like that sdk hooks into google ad manager which makes you build your own ad network. What did you do for the actual ads?